# Python Script - Working on Local Environment but not on Dev Server

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, operating-system

As the title says, I have build a Python script which works perfectly fine on my local system. However, the results are not the same on the development server I have. Both systems are running Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. I will provide more information below the code.

```
import os

matches = []
directory = '/home/mount/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.html'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, file))

print(matches)


for index, x in enumerate(matches):
    print(x)
    os.system(f'echo docker run --name nginx_{index} -p 8{index}:80 -v {x}:usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx')
```

The results on my local system are as follows:

```
['/home/mount/test/file2.html', '/home/mount/test/file.html', '/home/mount/test/lower/file3.html']
/home/mount/test/file2.html
docker run --name nginx_0 -p 80:80 -v /home/mount/test/file2.html:usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx
/home/mount/test/file.html
docker run --name nginx_1 -p 81:80 -v /home/mount/test/file.html:usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx
/home/mount/test/lower/file3.html
docker run --name nginx_2 -p 82:80 -v /home/mount/test/lower/file3.html:usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx
```

Which is exactly what I want. Basically the script looks for html files in directories in or below the one provided at the top of the code. It then adds them to a list which then adds to a string which takes the form of a docker command.

On the server the only output I am getting is :

```
[]
```

Which tells me that the for loop is not working properly. However, I am not receiving any errors running the code in terminal, just the empty array. My thought is that it might be a problem with the OS module but I'm not sure how to check this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `/home/mount/` exists on your server?

Comment: @Dinari I have changed the path on the server to /home/Documents/scripts which as I pwd in the directory I see is the incorrect path. Sigh. Will change and then update.

Comment: @Dinari yep that was exactly the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, I just had the wrong directory written out in my code. It's always a stupid mistake like that.